# JQuery applying change for each select element in a div section

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: callback.call is not a function
>
> value = callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]);

With the following code:

```
$("#pagingDetails select").each($(this).change(RefreshSearchResults));
$("#peopleSearchFilter select").each($(this).change(RefreshSearchResults));
$("#peopleSearchFilter input:checkbox").each($(this).click(RefreshSearchResults));
```

Where my function `RefreshSearchResults` makes an Ajax request to the server to get new search results based on the search criteria or paging provided by the user through the `select` and `checkbox` elements in the`pagingDetails` div and `personSearchFilter` div.

What am I don't wrong?

Thanks,

-Frinny

Comment: The `.each()` methods are unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Fixed this by changing it to the following:
        $("#pagingDetails select").change(RefreshSearchResults);
        $("#peopleSearchFilter select").change(RefreshSearchResults);
        $("#peopleSearchFilter input:checkbox").click(RefreshSearchResults);

Comment: Could you please post this as an answer so that I can mark it as such? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to loop into the stack, you can simply bind on the jQuery object

```
$("#pagingDetails select").change(RefreshSearchResults);
$("#peopleSearchFilter select").change(RefreshSearchResults);
$("#peopleSearchFilter input:checkbox").click(RefreshSearchResults);
```

Also, as the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/#each-functionindex--Element) say, `.each()` need a function as argument, not an "action".

For future reference, a working code (event if it is useless) would look like this :

```
$('selector').each(function(){
    $(this).change(function);
})
```